# Rails - Rspec test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to expect a method call with any arguments, but I do want to manually check the arguments to I do an expect with a do block.

I am getting an exception saying that the method was invoked twice, but the logs I have in that method show that it only got called once. Any idea what's causing this?

**Method to be tested**

```
  def users
    pp ('Users got called') # only gets logged once
    render(template: 'users-template.json.jbuilder', locals: { users: @users })
  end
```

**Test**

```
  # Test
  describe 'users' do
    it 'Should only list users' do    
      expect(controller).to receive(:render) do |params|
        pp (params.class)
      end

      get :users
    end
  end
```

**Exception**

```
 Failure/Error: expect(controller).to receive(:render) do |params|
   (#<API::V2::MyController:0x0000010c95d438>).render(any args)
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 2 times with any arguments


EDIT:
```

If I uncomment the line of code that triggers the method calls it says 0 times with any arguments.

Comment: Firstly - why are we checking for "render" explicitly? Secondly - for debugging purposes, you can add `at_least(:once)` and it will stop failing, so you can see what the params are.

Comment: @TarynEast Checking for render to make sure that the correct parameters are passed to my template

Comment: Could it be in the containing describe/context blocks (e.g. in let/before blocks)?